# Multi Sheet Inventory that allows for an ordered quantity to be entered, once product delivered, the stock column updates to existing + ordered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, macro-button

I've been breaking my head over this one.

I have an inventory that has 10 sheets and a 500 different items.  [Stock entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95kwn.png) To enter data, you can select the manufacturer (Lieferant), the page on which this item is located (Seite) and then the amount ordered (Anzahl). Once that is entered, the ordered amount automatically shows up on the correct sheet, in the row of that item. [Stock overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hteUr.png) You can see that the "amount ordered" was transferred into column "Bestellt" (Ordered) and the current stock levels are in column "Lagerbestand" (Stock).

Now to the problem: When the item is delivered, and I remove it from the "Stock Entry" sheet it disappears from the Ordered column. However, I would like the Stock (Lagerbestand) to increase by the amount that was ordered. I know that I'll need a macro for that, but I can't for the life of me know where to start with my limited VBA knowledge.

I've tried:

```vb
Sub CheckDuplicate()

    'Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim match As Range
    
    'Set the worksheet variable to the active worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'Set the range variable to column D in the worksheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("D:D")
    
    'Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng
        'If the value in the cell is not blank
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            'Search the range for a duplicate of the cell's value
            Set match = rng.Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            'If a match is found and it is not the original cell
            If Not match Is Nothing And match.Address <> cell.Address Then
                'Add the value in Bestellung!F6 to the cell 4 columns to the right of the duplicate
                ws.Cells(match.Row, match.Column + 4).Value = ws.Cells(match.Row, match.Column + 4).Value + ws.Cells(cell.Row, 6).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

But nothing happens when used.

I'd appreciate any help and am happy to clarify anything.

Comment: Full on inventory management is better handled by a database than a spreadsheet. You'll be able to handle transactions far better and in a more scalable way.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Although you can use a spreadsheet as a database, you should think about getting accounting/inventory management software. Yes, there is a learning curve there, but there is a learning curve here with VBA. Make use of VBA debugging features like viewing watch and intermediate windows, and stepping through your program. Good luck.